# WatermarkTextBox Control with XAML in Metro Style Application

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I'm learning stage in XAML Metro Style Application. I want to create simple login page with WatermarkTextBox control as following image. My problem is that, i want to set WatermarkTextBox's watermark text (Email Id as Password Text) vertical middle.

[image]

My XMAL line of code as following

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Login"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Controls="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"
    x:Class="Login.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="163*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="101*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="112*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="114*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="116*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="162*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Controls:WatermarkTextBox WatermarkText="Email Id"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="502,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="60" Width="433" FontFamily="Andalus" FontSize="18" Padding="10, 15, 0, 0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="PasswordWatermark" Text="Password"  IsHitTestVisible="False" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Andalus" Width="433" Height="60" Margin="502,0,425,52" Padding="10, 15, 0, 0"/>
        <PasswordBox x:Name="pbPassword" LostFocus="PasswordLostFocus" GotFocus="PasswordGotFocus" Grid.Row="2" FontFamily="Andalus" FontSize="18" Margin="502,0,425,52" Opacity="0" Width="433" Height="60" Padding="10, 15, 0, 0"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnLogin" Content="Login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="791,0,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Width="147" FontFamily="Andalus" FontSize="18" Background="#FF385936" BorderBrush="#FF644F4F"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

.CS

```
private void PasswordLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckPasswordWatermark();
}

private void CheckPasswordWatermark()
{
     var passwordEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pbPassword.Password);
     PasswordWatermark.Opacity = passwordEmpty ? 100 : 0;
     pbPassword.Opacity = passwordEmpty ? 0 : 100;
}

private void PasswordGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     PasswordWatermark.Opacity = 0;
     pbPassword.Opacity = 100;
}
```

Your help is a grate appreciate. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am not using Vs 2012, so I can't test it. I am coding in notepad. But  it might be help:

```
 <Controls:WatermarkTextBox WatermarkText="Email Id"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="502,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" 
     VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="60" Width="433" FontFamily="Andalus" FontSize="18" Padding="10, 15, 0, 0">
    <Controls:WatermarkTextBox.WatermarkTextStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />  
        </Style>            
    </Controls:WatermarkTextBox.WatermarkTextStyle>         
 <Controls:WatermarkTextBox/>
```

If possible, tell me result.

Comment: Sir, I'm checked it but not working this! Please give any other solution.

Comment: May be because of Padding? Cretae a new empty project and add a WatermarkTextBox control. And test my solution on that project. See if it is what you need. And then tell me result. Thanks.

Comment: Sir, When i go for enter text into textbox, entered text put into center, but watermark text (e.g. Email ID) not put into vertical center. Please help me. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @user1273915 I have updated question, please tell me result after changes.

Comment: Wowwwwwwww, It's working sir. A lot of thanks to you. One more thing, Which line of code you have given, it's solved my another problem too so thanks again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but text box contains the VerticalContentAlignment and HorizontalContentAlignment properties.

Those are the ones that tell the control how to align the text inside of them.